# Has Windows an integrated built-in C/C++ compiler package?

Tags: c++, c, windows, native

I would like to be able to compile C and C++ code under the Windows environment without using an IDE, just by using the Windows Command prompt (cmd.exe).

I come from Linux, where you are be able to install the `gcc` package with just a command in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install gcc
```

I wonder if there is a C/C++ compiler collection in a package inside the Windows install folders, just like the ones in Linux, I just need to install.

What also gives me a reason to ask this question is:

Since the kernel of Windows and the Windows API are written in C, and many of the high-level applications of the actual Windows 10 release are written in C++, it would be reasonable to also directly provide a suitable compiler suite. This is my thought modell, does not need to match reality.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look into [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) if you want to install GCC on Windows. It's also possible to compile code using cl.exe on the command line.

Comment: " it would be reasonable to also directly provide a suitable compiler suite" windows isnt really the OS that is known to put the user in control ;)

Comment: You can install the C++ microsoft toolset (not from the command line) Then you can use the "native" windows compiler (cl.exe) without installing an IDE. Also you can use MinGW, which lets you install a gcc for windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no in-built compiler. You need to install one.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio free version but never use the IDE. I compile from a console command line with `NMAKE` although I have to tweak the `PATH` setting, and environment variables. I do it with a batch file which calls `vcvarsall.bat` (somewhere in the VC installation folders) and `NMAKE` with a local `MAKEFILE`. It wasn't the easiest thing to set up.

Comment: A compiler is not an essential component of Windows because building from source yourself is not the usual way to obtain a binary for most Windows users. Shipping a compiler and the necessary development components would thus be wasteful in most cases.

Comment: @Blaze Is `cl.exe` natively included in a Windows Distribution? And if so, Isn´t that the thing I am looking for? Or are there any disadvantages about `cl.exe`? Also can I compile C and C++ code with it?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica it does have its quirks sometimes, but it works well enough. It's not natively included in Windows, however. I don't think any C or C++ compiler is.

Comment: @Blaze Ok, but where is `cl.exe` from? Microsoft Visual C++ (MSVC)? Can I later use it without the IDE?

Comment: That's right. It's from Visual Studio, and it can also be installed with the VS Build Tools if you don't want the IDE.

Comment: Property -> Configuration Properties -> Advance -> C++/CLI properties:
Common language Runtime Support need to be setup.
This will be available in Visual Studio

Comment: `apt install gcc`  how is that built in?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I can´t speak for all Linux distributions, but on my Linux distribution, Ubuntu Pengolin, the `gcc` package was already part of the distribution itself. No need to download or get the respective package elsewhere. This is what I meant with "in-built". No need for further acquirement of any software.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even though this installation process, you have talked about, is very honorable, but is `NMAKE.exe` really a solid equivalent to a compiler? Why do you use that instead of a regular compiler?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica `NMAKE` calls `cl.exe` and (if successful) `link.exe`. That's the MSVC compiler, not a different one.

Comment: "Since the kernel of Windows and the Windows API are written in C, and many of the high-level applications of the actual Windows 10 release are written in C++, it would be *reasonable* to also directly provide a suitable compiler suite.", No there need not be a compiler provided for all your description, it runs without a compiler.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Since the kernel of Windows and the Windows API are written in C

Microsoft doesn't ship a compiler, or the required [Windows SDK headers/libs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (also includes a bunch of other useful development tools) for Windows in the installation. 
 Microsoft Visual C++ (part of [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/)) would be the equivalent "built in" choice although I am not sure if Microsoft ever specify exactly which version they use for a given Windows build and it is common to have lots of software built with different compilers/versions (including the various non-Microsoft ones).

As well as the full Visual Studio package with the IDE and other tools. Microsoft provide some components separately, such as the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).

I am sure this is for many reasons like most users not being interested in compiling their own software, and Microsoft still sells Visual Studio separately to larger organisations (historically to most serious users, but "Community" edition is now pretty nonrestrictive for individuals and small business).

Answer (score 10):

Strangely enough it doesn't come with a C compiler, we need to install one,  [Mingw-w64](https://github.com/mingw-w64/mingw-w64.github.io/) is allways my  choice, you will need to [add the path in environment variables](http://www.codebind.com/cprogramming/install-mingw-windows-10-gcc/) (step 12), if you want to use it anywhere. You can then use the `gcc` command where it's more convenient like in Linux, don't forget to open a new cmd after the changes for them to take effect.

Unfortunately, Windows doesn't have the command line tools for installing/removing stuff and the great repository infrastructure we know and love from Linux.

Comment: If instead of installing just GCC you install the entire MSYS2 toolkit, you'll get the commandline tools linked to a package repository that works just as well as the linux distributions.

Comment: @anastaciu To use MingW is a great alternative. I was known of using MingW before. Nonetheless, I would like to know more about Microsoft´s own ways before using a third-party compiler suite such as `gcc` in Windows by the MingW implementation. Thank you, anastaciu for the tip.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica that is a good mindset, I use Visual Studio Community 2019 and it has come a long way, it's now a great IDE, one of my favourites, that said, it's built-in development tools were not really designed with cmd line usage in mind, it seems to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The big big caveat with Mingw is that it uses a different, incompatible ABI from MSVC. That means you cannot use mingw gcc with C++ libraries that have been compiled for MSVC use. The opposite is also true, leading to the unfortunate situation that we have two incompatible C++ ecosystems on Windows: MSVC being the native one and Mingw being the one for interacting with GNU components that have not been ported to MSVC. Note that clang for Windows, unlike mingw's gcc, is able to generate native C++ applications with the MSVC ABI.

Answer (score 6):

You will need two things:

- The command-line build tools. These can be found on the [Visual Studio Downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) page under *Tools for Visual Studio* -> *Build Tools for Visual Studio*. This will include the compiler (`cl.exe`) and linker (`link.exe`) for the MSVC build toolchain.
- The Windows SDK. The latest version of the SDK can currently be [found here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). This page has a tendency to move around, but googling for Windows SDK usually gives you the right page immediately. The SDK contains all the headers and libraries required to build Windows applications and make use of the Windows native API. The Windows SDK contains a lot of stuff which you may or may not need. You will almost certainly want to install the `Windows SDK for Desktop C++ x86 Apps` and `Windows SDK for Desktop C++ amd64 Apps` components. Most of the other stuff should be optional, but some of it is nonetheless highly useful.
- You may want to download additional packages such as the [Windows Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools) (which is an entirely *different* application than the Visual Studio debugger) or the [Driver SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk), depending on what kind of things you want to develop.

Note that even if you don't intend to use the IDE in the end, installing the full Community Edition of Visual Studio is a far more convenient way to get a working build environment, so unless you have a really good reason not to, just go with the full package and choose to never open the IDE.

Answer (score 6):

The built in compilers available on Windows 10 are for VisualBasic, C#, JScript.
To improve speed & performance of apps, "[ngen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator) creates native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead of using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly".

For low level programmers, ilasm.exe [(IL Assembler)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3778/Introduction-to-IL-Assembly-Language) ships with Windows, which also facilitates "tool and compiler" development; so you could even create your own language or build a better compiler for a current one, or "debug your code at low level and understand how .NET deals with your high level code", or "write your own compiler for a new .NET language."

For web programmers, [AspNetCompiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/aspnetcompiler-task?view=vs-2019) precompiles server-side ASP.NET web-applications, therefore [helps application performance because end users do not encounter a delay on the first request to the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms229863(v=vs.100)).

All Compilers & assemblers come as builtin with Windows without IDE and can be run from "the Windows Command prompt (cmd.exe)", so no extra downloads necessary; located in folder: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.x.xxxxx\ .

Note: [C#](https://www.educba.com/c-sharp-vs-java-performance/) is based on JScript.

Compilers:

- vbc.exe
- csc.exe
- jsc.exe
- ilasm.exe
- ngen.exe
- aspnet_compiler.exe

**Addendum**:

If you still are looking for a C compiler to handle some C source codes you already have spent your life on, then (without downloading) you can make/[write a C compiler](https://norasandler.com/2017/11/29/Write-a-Compiler.html), in a high level language, then optimize it with a low level language.

[This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/february/create-a-language-compiler-for-the-net-framework-using-csharp) will "introduce you to the high-level architecture, theory, and .NET Framework APIs that are required to build your own .NET compiler" in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can to use `gcc` for windows. For e.g. `mingw`, `tdm-gcc`, `mingw-68`, `Cygwin`  etc. Each of them allows you to work on `c/c++`. But if you are not sure about the installation process, and don't want to do all the work by yourself, the easiest solution is to download something like `dev-c++` or `code-blocks`.

cygwin: https://cygwin.com/
mingw-64: http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php
Downloadable file can be found here (for `mingw`, `dev-c++`): https://sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can also install Microsoft compiler. I usually do it by installing the whole visual studio.

Comment: What is the name of that "Microsoft compiler" and how can install this one separately? And can I later also use this compiler without the IDE when installing it with it? With "visual studio" Do you mean Microsoft Visual Studio or Microsoft Visual C++?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B. You commonly obtain MSVC by installing Visual Studio (as this way you also get all the necessary libraries/framework components for the kind of development you want to do). Note that Visual Studio has free licenses (the non-free licenses primarily add enterprise/team features), but is closed source (like most of the MS ecosystem).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Ok, I understood the MSVC and Visual Studio part. But what about that "Microsoft compiler" P__J__ has stated. Am I right in the assumption, that this "Microsoft compiler" is `cl.exe`? And can I later use this compiler without the IDE?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica That's the compiler, yes. The linker is `link.exe`. You might want to look around https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-building-reference?view=vs-2019, because those two aren't the only pieces of the toolchain. Yes, you can use all this without the IDE. I'm not sure if you can skip installing the IDE in the first place.

Comment: If you really want to use MSVC in the command line you you have some [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiling-a-c-cpp-program?view=vs-2019) that explain it's usage, I would still recomend the use of gcc, I did that and my transition was seamless.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica Really just a "compiler" itself isn't useful, GCC is also multiple components and other Linux packages provide essentials like C runtimes and headers. VS or the standalone build tools have command line options, but it is fairly rare to develop that way, and even then using `msbuild` on a VS project file rather than directly `cl.exe`/`link.exe`/etc. is common.

Comment: @P__J__ I´m a hardliner. I like to make things clear as possible because often times in my life I did encoutered situations already where little confusions made the difference and caused major problems. So it is just for the sake of not causing confusions. Thank you for your patience.