# Is there a single official C compiler, and how do I install it?

Tags: c, windows, installation, compilation

I'm trying to install the C compiler onto my Windows 10 machine to be able to learn to develop in C. After looking around I found [this mirror page](ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-10.1.0/) linked by [this official looking](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) site, and downloaded and uncompressed the folder. I also tried `git clone`ing linked from [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/git.html).

Both folders look identical, and I can't find any executables in either. My hunch is that the actual compiler needs to be generated or compiled with the files found in the folders.

After looking at online tutorials most of them install third-party package managers to then install gcc from there, but I'd rather just install it directly (if thats possible in the first place). I'm not really sure if there *is* a single true C compiler because of this.

Could someone please clarify how this system works, and what I need to do to get it working. Thanks! :D

Comment: Note: C does not specify an official compiler.  `gcc` may have an authoritative site per target compiler platform, but `gcc` is one of [many C compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:C_compilers).

Comment: Are you sure that you insist on the "official" one (which is not even clearly defined as the other comment pointed out)? In your situation I would look for a "convenient" installation. If you agree, then the selection is most wisely based on asking your friends/colleagues/fellows, because you will have questions and they are primarily best answered by any human you can directly ask. StackOverflow is only second place. If that does not help you select one I recommend to use yoru favoritate search engine on "install gcc". In mine, the 10th result is my favorite.

Comment: There is no single c compiler, but gcc is probably the most popular one. If you want to install it download MinGW, then install gcc from that :)

Comment: Maybe go on step further towards "convenient" and search for "free IDE C" my favorite is the 6th result. But of course this is not to tell you my favorite in a hidden way. You just look at the results, check the first few out and decide based on what you like best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*Is there a single official C compiler, and how do I install it?*"

No, there is no compiler provided by the C standard and thus no way to install it.

You have to use a third-party compiler. The most common for Linux and macOS are called GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) and Clang.

Since you ask for Windows, there are several C compilers available.

Take a look at the answers and comments to this question of mine a while ago:

[Has Windows an integrated built-in C/C++ compiler package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820244/has-windows-a-built-in-native-c-c-compiler-package)

There you can find the at least many options.

The way to install you can find in the respective documentations and isn't object to be defined here as this would explode the frame.

My personal recommendation is GCC with the [MingW_64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) package. How you install it, you can find, as said, in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a single official C compiler? No.

Are you sure that you insist on the "official" one (which is not even clearly defined as the other comment pointed out)?
In your situation I would look for a "convenient" installation.

This more or less leads to the answer to "How to install it?"
The selection and indirectly the way to install it, is most wisely based on asking your friends/colleagues/fellows, because you will have questions and they are primarily best answered by any human you can directly ask. StackOverflow is only second place.
If that does not help you selecting one, I recommend to use yoru favorite search engine on "install gcc". In mine, the 10th result is my favorite.

Maybe go one step further towards "convenient" and search for "free IDE C" my favorite is the 6th result.
But of course this is not to tell you my favorite in a hidden way. You just look at the results, check the first few out and decide based on what you like best.

Comment: And well, if you want to know, one of the comments on your question spilled the secret of my favorite, conveniently installed, compiler. ;-) and you can get it in a form which brings a decent free IDE if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no official C compiler on any platform, and gcc is not a Windows program. The two main toolkits which provide C a compiler on Windows are [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) and [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Both include a port of gcc, and after installing either one, you can use the `gcc` command to compile your C code.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not make a C compiler. They produce Visual Studio, which contains a C++ compiler that will compile a large subset of C programs, but they have made it clear that they have no intention of keeping up with the latest C standards.

The most popular C compilers on most platforms (Windows included) are GCC and CLANG/LLVM.